# Not able to read data from serial port in QT

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I am trying to read data from e sensor that is connected over a serial port.
My code looks like this:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QSerialPort serial;

serial.setPortName("COM4");


if(serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){
    qDebug() << "connection successful";
}else{
    qDebug() << "connection failed";
}

serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

serial.waitForReadyRead(3000);
qDebug() << serial.errorString();

QTimer::singleShot(2000, &a, &QApplication::quit);

return a.exec();
```

The problem is that `waitForReadyRead` times out and no data is ever ready to be received.
Any suggestions what I am doing wrong or what I might be missing?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're trying to do here. waitForReadyRead() is a blocking function that returns a bool (which you're not consuming). I'd prefer to know the value of this return, rather than merely outputting an error string. And your timer can't begin until the waitForReadyRead has ended, so I don't understand its purpose. Also...you don't have a read function...is this intentional? Finally, not to belabor the obvious, but...are you sure there is input data available on the serial port?

Comment: @mzimmers Thanks a lot for your advice. In fact the problem was that there was no data available on the serial port. The sensor I am using needs to receive a signal before it sends data over the serial port.